# How can I validate or preview an update before execution in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo document which I would like to update:

```
votes: [{
  name: 'Bugs Bunny',
  percentage: 50
}, {
  name: 'Mickey Mouse',
  percentage: 49
}]
```

I want to make sure that the sum of `percentage` will never exceed 100, when updating an object in the array or adding a new object to the array.

I am wondering is there a way to preview updates and then save them?
Or is there a way to rollback to the previous document when `percentage > 100`?

I've read I can't use validators: [How validate $push in update request mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572824/how-validate-push-in-update-request-mongoose)

Comment: You can do such check and update. The features you may want to look at are the `$expr` for verifying the condition. The $expr allows querying using aggregation operators and perform arithmetic on existing data in a document. Another feature you can use is the _Updates with Aggregation Pipeline_.